# Google Datastore reverse an update or delete?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there any way to reverse or rollback an update or set of updates (or deletions) in Google Cloud Datastore? I suppose the only way is rolling back a transaction or restoring from a backup that was previously made?

Or I suppose you could be clever and make duplicates of entities before updating or deleting them, and then delete these duplicates when a full backup is made?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to undo delete or update in the Datastore.

Google Cloud Storage supports object versioning. You may implement similar mechanism in the Datastore by adding "version" and/or "last_update" properties to your entities. Then you can either keep the full history of changes/deletes, or discard some old versions after a certain period of time.